# jQuery nth-child filter li.class

Tags: jquery, css

Short CSS code:

```
 .hide {display: none;}
```

This is the HTML:

```
         <ul>
            <li class="title">Who Are You?</li>
            <li class="fields">
                <label>*First Name:</label><br />
                <input id="first_name" class="req" type="text" /><br />
                <label>Middle Name:</label><br />
                <input id="middle_name" type="text" /><br />
                <label>Last Name Name:</label><br />
                <input id="last_name" type="text" /><br />
                <label>*Email:</label><br />
                <input id="email" class="req" type="text" /><br />
            </li>
            <li class="title">Where Are You?</li>
            <li class="fields">
                <label>City:</label><br />
                <input id="city" type="text" /><br />
                <label>*State:</label><br />
                <input id="state" class="req" type="text" /><br />
                <label>Country:</label><br />
                <input id="country" type="text" /><br />
            </li>
            <li class="title">What Do You Do?</li>
            <li class="fields">
                <label>*Occupation:</label><br />
                <input id="occupation" class="req" type="text" /><br />
                <label>Company</label><br />
                <input id="company" type="text" /><br />
                <label>Company Location:</label><br />
                <input id="location" type="text" /><br />
            </li>
        </ul>
```

This is the jQuery*:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li.fields').filter(':nth-child(n+4)').addClass('hide');
});
```

*I didn't write the code myself

My trouble is that I don't know how this jQ code is filtering. It hides the second and third li element which includes the class "fields", but shouldn't it hide from the Last Name[...] and further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery selector and filter that you have works as follows.

First, the `li.fields` picks out the `li` elements with the class `.fields`, which turns out to be the 2nd, 4th, and 6th child elements of the `ul`. (To clarify, the 1st, 3rd and 5th child elements have the `.title` class.) Remember that `n` takes on the values of 0, 1, 2,...

The filtering by `:nth-child(n+4)` then picks out the 4th, 5th, 6th... child elements, which means that the 4th and 6th `li` elements are assigned the `.hide` class, which hides them.

The `label` elements are children of the corresponding `li` elements, not the `ul` element, hence, they don't factor into the selection.

Comment: So the :nth-child actually searches for all the siblings of the li element, then only picks the (n+4) with the .fields class, n starting from 0 here

Thank you very much!!